# Getting specific value from Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing a name check from a lookup and the below is my jQuery

```
var name = $('input[name=name]').val();
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"assets/inc/namecheck.php",
    data:"name="+name,
    success:function(data){
        var expire = $(data).attr('data-bind-name');
        console.log(expire);
        console.log(data);
        $('.results').html(expire);
    }
});
```

Inside my `namecheck.php` is my function to get the content from a url. This content is passed back to the `.ajax()` request but I'm trying to only get the `.val()` from the attribute `.attr('data-bind-name')`

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Instead `console.log` is only passing through the entire page via the `data` variable

Comment: Parse the data in php and send it back to jquery. `data` is a whole webpage, and you are passing it as a jquery selector! `$(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally need to format your data using something like [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) first. I mean, your `get_data` function returns a simple string (assuming you have no errors because you have no error checking) and you're just dumping this back? What does the URL you're using `CURL` to get return?

Comment: The URL returns an entire html page but I am trying to pinpoint 1 specific part of that page which has the results of my `name` variable

Comment: Ok, that gives us something more to work with. If you need to parse an HTML page, I would recommend using something like [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to do it